# Update cell Google Sheet API

Tags: google-sheets-api

Trying to update a cell in a Google Sheet with the source attached, I find the error "Invalid value at 'requests[0].update_cells' (oneof), oneof field 'area' is already set. Cannot set 'start'", and I don't know what I am doing wrong

```
[{
    "updateCells"={
        "fields"="totalUpdatedCells", 
        "range"={
            "endColumnIndex"=179, 
            "endRowIndex"=7, 
            "sheetId"=XXXXX, 
            "startColumnIndex"=179, 
            "startRowIndex"=7
        }, 
        "rows"=[
            {
                "values"=[
                    {
                        "userEnteredValue"={
                            "stringValue"="My text"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ], 
        "start"={
            "columnIndex"=179, 
            "rowIndex"=7, 
            "sheetId"=XXXXX
        }
    }
}]
```

This is the concrete error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid value at 'requests[0].update_cells' (oneof), oneof field 'area' is already set. Cannot set 'start'",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid value at 'requests[0].update_cells' (oneof), oneof field 'area' is already set. Cannot set 'start'",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

A hint from where can I throw?

EDIT for @Tanaike:

The body of request:

```
{
   "requests"=   [
      {
         "updateCells"= {
            "fields"="userEnteredValue",
            "rows"= [
               {
                  "values"= [
                     {
                        "userEnteredValue"= {
                           "stringValue"="My text"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "start"=            {
               "columnIndex"=179,
               "rowIndex"=7,
               "sheetId"=XXXXX
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

and the error of request:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid requests[0].updateCells: GridCoordinate.columnIndex[179] is after last column in grid[25]",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid requests[0].updateCells: GridCoordinate.columnIndex[179] is after last column in grid[25]",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the goal you want?

Comment: @Tanaike I want to update the contents of a cell

Comment: Thank you for replying. How about removing the property of `range` and modifying the fields to `userEnteredValue`? If that modification didn't work, please provide the whole request body for replicating your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike for the error I think the range field should be included

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your script, `"columnIndex"=179` and `"rowIndex"=7` are used. This means the cell `FX8`. So I'm thinking that you want to put the text to the cell `FX8`. From your error message, it is found that the column length of your sheet is less than 180 columns. So your consideration of `I think the range field should be included` is not correct. If you want to put the text to the cell `FX8`, please add the columns.

Comment: OMG the error was mine, change columns by rows, I wanted to update the G179 range ... Thanks @Tanaike for the help received

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the body of the request in case another user encounters the same problem:

```
{
  requests=[
    {
      updateCells={
        fields=userEnteredValue,
        rows=[
          {
            values=[
              {
                userEnteredValue={
                  stringValue=My text
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        start={
          columnIndex=6,
          rowIndex=178,
          sheetId=XXXXX
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks to @Tanaike for helping me find the answer